# How to Measure the ROI from SEO Campaigns

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

How can I measure SEO activities ROI: including on-page and Off-page SEO.

As you know any big business has a common organic traffic growth.

also, SEO can affect direct traffic.

so is there any way to measure SEO ROI campaigns?

Answer (score 2):

To Analyse your ROI (Return on Investments) you should do some homework and additional configuration in Google Analytics, if you want to do it automatically. Here is a good resource [How to do ROI Analysis in Google Analytics](https://www.optimizesmart.com/roi-analysis-google-analytics/) Here you will find detailed instruction how to do this calculation in Google Analytics. Please make higher attention to Cost Data imports. Here you need to import your cost data against the organic channel.

You can do it manually as well, by using [ROI Calculator](https://financial-calculators.com/roi-calculator)

Some notes about data what you can use for your calculation:

1. You can't analyse specific keywords and separate on-site/off-site SEO. You should make a calculation based on all sales from Organic Channel.
2. Additionally, if you have got very strong and traffic driven backlinks, you can include in calculation sales from these specific backlinks, i.e. use Referrals from your specific backlinks and sales what you got from visitors from these websites. To easier track your backlink referrals, you can create a custom Segmentation Filter in Google Analytics. In the filter, you include your off-site backlinks as referrals.
3. By default Google Analytics use [Last Non-Direct Click](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2017/12/04/google-analytics-attribution-models/#last-non-direct-click) attribution modelling. It means that the conversion data are added for your last non-direct click. You can do customisation here and choose which is more relevant for your customers' journeys.
4. No matter how you calculate and what methods you choose, just make sure that Goal Tracking and E-Commerce Tracking is configured properly and you see sales in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a decent tracking platform for this, be it GA or Clicky, and track how well those visitors are converting in sales and clients. You can do that with GA, but of course, you need to organize all of your data.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how much of these traffic are from common organic search and how much are the result of SEO activities and also I do not know how much of organic traffic turns to direct traffic.